# LoggerBase.cs getting stuck in a loop on Android

Tags: azure, active-directory, adal

I've pulled some code which works fine in one Xamarin Forms project into another one, iOS still works fine

Android however gets stuck when you've tried to authenticate. Looking at the logger, this happens:

[Mono] Assembly Ref addref Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory[0xb0be9820] -> System.Runtime.Serialization[0xa7b84420]: 4
[Mono] Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.Serialization[0xa7b84420] -> System.Core[0xa60eaae0]: 10
[] 2018-02-23T23:06:37.9741530Z: 5fe3f680-5cc2-4ff7-a615-2e50b2ba4ae2 - LoggerBase.cs: Loading from cache.
[] 2018-02-23T23:06:37.9838740Z: 5fe3f680-5cc2-4ff7-a615-2e50b2ba4ae2 - LoggerBase.cs: Looking up cache for a token...
[] 2018-02-23T23:06:37.9878000Z: 5fe3f680-5cc2-4ff7-a615-2e50b2ba4ae2 - LoggerBase.cs: No matching token was found in the cache

It seems to not be storing a valid token on the initial login, and thereafter not returning to the login page, so it's just stuck

Since the code still works in other project, I figure either this specific project has cached something that's not getting deleted on clean, or the android emulator has some common settings that don't get flushed (I've made another emulator, same result)

Any idea how to resolve?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in iOS